# Android: Accessing DB

Tags: android, database, cursor

I have the following code:

```
DbAdapter dbAdapter = new DbAdapter(this);
dbAdapter.open();
ArrayList<String> queryResultList = new ArrayList<String>();
Cursor cur = dbAdapter.db.query("mytable", columns, where, null, groupBy, null, null);      
cur.moveToFirst();
while (cur.isAfterLast() == false) 
{
        queryResultList.add(cur.getString(0));
    cur.moveToNext();
}
cur.close();

dbAdapter.close();
```

This code runs on a device where it never run before, i.e. a wiped emulator as well as a Samsung Galaxy S device where the app was removed after the first trial. That means the database I am reading is being created first on the device. It is a custom database.

On 2.2 it runs perfectly fine, on 2.1-update1 (API Level 7) it wont, the isAfterLast() is always true, but it is there since API Level 1. Any one an idea? Or an idea what I can do to figure out?

Thanks, A.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, why not use:

```
Cursor cur = ...;
while (cur.moveToNext()) {
  queryResultList.add(cur.getString(0));
}
cur.close();
```